# Dictionary making weird key:value pairs

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to make a simple calculator, where you just type in something like "2+2*2" and it calculates the answer. First step was to find, and cut out the individual numbers, which I tried doing below.

```
print("Put an equals sign at the end to finish the equation.")
equation = input("Calculate: ")
symbols = ["+","-","*","/","="]
x = 0
for symbols in equation:
    subequation = {f"N{x}" : equation[0:equation.find(symbols)]}
    x = x + 1
print(subequation)
```

But when I input:

```
Calculate: 2+2*2=
```

I don't get the expected output of:

```
{'N0':'2+', 'N1':'2*','N2':'2='}
```

But rather:

```
{'N5': '2+2*2'}
```

I'm still very new to python, so please also tell me if there's anything I can do better. Thanks.

Comment: You overwrite the list of symbols in your for loop

Comment: You are changing the subequation in every loop. You probably want to create an empty dictionary outside the loop `subequation = {}` and then use `subequation[f"N{x}"]= equation[0:equation.find(symbols)]` inside the loop.

Comment: @EmiOB that would still give the same output.

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish I know that doesn't solve the issue, but I'm trying to figure out what the OPs actual intentions were

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to get? Why do you expect `{'N0':'2+', 'N1':'2*'}` this as output?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Your loop is using `symbols` as the loop variable. That overwrites the initial value of `symbols`. Start by changing the loop to `for symbol in symbols:`, and put a diagnostic `print()` call inside the loop. The other problem is that you clearly expect the loop to add new values to `subequation`. But it doesn't. Each time through the loop it creates a fresh dictionary with the last value found. Initialize the dictionary before the loop and do `subequation[f"N{x}"]` = somevalue` inside the loop. These fixes won't cure your problem but they will let you see what else is wrong.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the input string does not contain any one of the symbols?

Comment: I don't know how to reply to people here. I was expecting {'N0' : '2+', 'N1' : '2*'}, because I used the same kind of for loop in another program to ask how many numbers to add up. I tried copy pasting it in and changing variable names and such but that didn't work, so I ended up cutting it down and changing bits and bops until it at least didn't give me an error. The output I expected would follow the logic of my other program, as far as I can tell, so I must have had done something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of small changes to get the result you added to your question, so I will go through each one.

I've created an empty dictionary to store your sub equation in: `subequation = {}`

Your original for loop of `for symbols in equation:` would overwrite your list of symbols, I believe what you are trying to do is go through each of the symbols and check if they are in the equation, which you can do with a for loop and then an if statement as below:

```
for symbol in symbols:
    if symbol in equation:
```

As mentioned by Jhanzaib Humayun in the comments, you're overwriting your subequation in each loop, rather than adding, so they have provided the code to add to a dict as below:

```
subequation[f"N{x}"]= equation[0:equation.find(symbols)]
```

But `equation[0:equation.find(symbols)]` will always start from the begining of the equation and return everything up to (and not including the symbol), so would return:

```
{'N0': '2', 'N1': '2+2', 'N2': '2+2*2'}
```

Which is not what you want, so I changed this to:

```
equation[equation.find(symbol)-1:equation.find(symbol)+1]
```

Which will now only include the number and symbol, but as Titouan L commented, this won't work for numbers with multiple digits, so I have come up with a `last_symbol` variable which will work backwards from the symbol it's looking at to find the last one, and keep anything in between. I have done this as below:

```
last_symbol = max([i for i in range(equation.find(symbol)-1, 0, -1)
                   if equation[i] in symbols] + [-1])
subequation[f"N{x}"]= equation[last_symbol+1:equation.find(symbol)+1]
```

This works backwards from the symbol to find the indexes of all previous symbols (`[i for i in range(equation.find(symbol)-1, 0, -1) if equation[i] in symbols]`) and finds the maximum of this (i.e. the most recent).  I added [-1] to this list as for the first symbol, there will not be a previous symbol, and when adding to the dictionary, I have done `equation[last_symbol+1:equation.find(symbol)+1]`, so for the first symbol, this will go from `0:equation.find(symbol)+1`

The full code is:

```
print("Put an equals sign at the end to finish the equation.")
equation = input("Calculate: ")
symbols = ["+","-","*","/","="]
subequation = {}
x = 0
for symbol in symbols:
    if symbol in equation:

        last_symbol = max([i for i in range(equation.find(symbol)-1, 0, -1)
                           if equation[i] in symbols] + [-1])
        subequation[f"N{x}"]= equation[last_symbol+1:equation.find(symbol)+1]
        x = x + 1
print(subequation)
```

Which returns the below as desired:

```
{'N0': '2+', 'N1': '2*', 'N2': '2='}
```

Comment: With your solution, the user cannot use a number greater than 9, for instance 21 would become 1, since your only keep the last digit.

Comment: @TitouanL fair point, will have a think of how to do that

Comment: A solution would be to count the `isdigit()` characters between two symbols, but that's not really the purpose of OP's question.

Comment: @TitouanL I have come up with a solution, feels a little over complicated but will work for longer numbers now

Comment: This specific line of code feels complicated but the explanation is clear, good stuff and a working solution for OP !

Comment: Updated code to match OP's edit to the question :)

Comment: Thanks. The explanation would have been enough, but yeah ty for also making the code. I can't upvote for some reason though, is there another way to say this helped?

Comment: @Murkorus I think you need a certain reputation to upvote. If this helped you can accept the answer by clicking the tick mark under the up the vote bit :)

Answer (score 0):

As some comments mentionned, you overwrite your variable `subequation` each loop. On top of that, your variable `symbols` is overwritten by the loop variable.

In order to get the same output as you requested, I changed the for loop to iterate over each character and check if it match a symbol of the list `symbols`.

```
print("Put an equals sign at the end to finish the equation.")
equation = input("Calculate: ")
symbols = ["+", "-", "*", "/", "="]
subequation = {}
x = 0
for i in range(len(equation)):
    if equation[i] in symbols:
        subequation[f"N{x}"] = equation[x:i+1]
        x = i+1

print(subequation)
```

The output is the following :

```
{'N0': '2+', 'N2': '2*', 'N4': '2='}
```

Comment: This only works if you have one digit numbers.

Comment: No, `21+2+43=` correclty gives `{'N0': '21+', 'N3': '2+', 'N5': '43='}`. Why would you think that ?

Answer (score -1):

As Emi OB commented, you overwrite symbols, as well as subequation, in your for loop.

I think you mean something like this:

```
print("Put an equals sign at the end to finish the equation.")
equation = input("Calculate: ")
symbols = ["+","-","*","/","="]
subequation = {f"N{x+1}" : equation[0:equation.find(symbols[x])] for x in range(len(symbols))}
print(subequation)
```

Comment: Lol, you directly copied OP's code and made an edit to it. There is no closing parenthesis on the first line

Comment: Also, when i try to run the code with OP's input i get `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: How do you know that this is the intended output?